# filter a column in pandas with the comination of only a set of defined characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

l process a csv file with panda.
My task is to filter the file on the column called `manual_raw_value` as follow 
l want to keep only the rows that satisfy the following condition :

```
a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',':','/','.',',','%','$','€']
```

keep only the rows where the value of the cell in `manual_raw_value` is only the combination between the char described in `the list a` .

How can l do that ?
l tried the following where l removed the rows where there is alphabet in the cells.

```
 # coding: utf-8

import os
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',')
b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','g','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

joined_2 = "|".join(b)
mask_2 =  ~df['manual_raw_value'].str.contains(joined_2)
cols = ['manual_raw_value']
df = df[mask_2].reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv('file_2.csv',index=False,sep=',')
```

What is the efficient way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this *regex* `r'^[\d:/.,%$€]+$'` with `str.match`, `\d` is a short for `0-9`;
Here put the chars that you want to match in a character class `[\d:/.,%$€]`, this will then match any character in your list, then use anchor `^` and `$` to denote the start and end of the string,  `^[\d:/.,%$€]+$` would then match a string that has one or more (what *+* means here) chars interested:

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"manual_raw_value": ["1232", "sdk", ".32", "$299", "*23", "€21", "/21"]})

df
# manual_raw_value
#0  1232
#1  sdk
#2  .32
#3  $299
#4  *23
#5  €21
#6  /21

a = r'^[\d:/.,%$€]+$'

a
# '^[\\d:/\\.,%\\$\xe2\x82\xac]+$'

df[df.manual_raw_value.str.match(a)]

#manual_raw_value
#0  1232
#2  .32
#3  $299
#5  €21
#6  /21
```

Or to construct the pattern from list `a`:

```
pattern = '^[{}]+$'.format(''.join(a))

df[df.manual_raw_value.str.match(pattern)]
#manual_raw_value
#0  1232
#2  .32
#3  $299
#5  €21
#6  /21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isalpha`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isalpha.html) for filter:

```
df = df[~df['manual_raw_value'].str.isalpha()]
#borrowing data from another answer
print (df)
  manual_raw_value
0             1232
2              .32
3             $299
4              *23
5              €21
6              /21
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"manual_raw_value": ["1232", "sdk", ".32", "$299", "*23", "€21", "/21"]})
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

In [99]: %timeit df[df.manual_raw_value.str.match(r'^[\d:/.,%$€]+$')]
10 loops, best of 3: 75.2 ms per loop

In [100]: %timeit df[~df['manual_raw_value'].str.isalpha()]
10 loops, best of 3: 21.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: thank you . but islpha() is a static method , l would like to add also '-' , '_' this is why l did the following  :  b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','g','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','_','-']

Comment: Hmmm, if need filter by `list a` only then need another solution. I was wrong you need filter only non alphabetic values.

Comment: But if need remove only alphabetic, `-` and empty strings `df[~df.manual_raw_value.str.match(r'^[a-zA-Z-]*$')]` should works.